# Kubernetes static web application deployment scenario

Tags: static-content, deployment

I was wondering what is best way to setup a **static** web application in kubernetes:

1. Place web app files inside the container image.
2. Place web app files in a share volume (mounted to pods).

In scenario #1 for every release (minor or major), we should deploy a new image and update the deployment.
In scenario #2 since files are in a shared location (like NFS share), it is easy to update files and releases without changing the kubernetes deployment.
**So what is the recommended way for this scenario?**

Answer (score 3):

First, in my opinion your deployment has to be immutable.
Each release is tagged and you have a kind of bijection between your docker image and your git tags.

Second, without an NFS share or a PVC you are reducing the complexity of your deployment and  the network traffic.

So, as a general best practice: Keep it simple and immutable!

Comment: I also think 1st solution is better because, as you mentioned, there isn't need for complex storage solutions. I just want see opinions.